# Start/Bind a service in UiAutomatorTestCase

Tags: android, android-intent, android-uiautomator

I have a `UiAutomatorTestCase`:

```
public class MyUiTest extends UiAutomatorTestCase {   

   public void testMe() throws UiObjectNotFoundException {   
      getUiDevice().pressHome();

      //How can I start/bind a service in the test case?
      //Seems I am not able to get a context in UiAutomatorTestCase
   }
}
```

I am wondering, is it possible to start/bind a service by using `startService(...)` or `bindService(...)` in this class?

Answer (score 3):

You could try to use:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("am start -n package/activity");
```

The code above executes the command in the Android OS shell. This should start an application. For example, to start settings you could replace package/activity with com.android.settings/.Settings.

I don't know if this is what you are looking for. You could give it a shot.

Comment: Could you please explain what does the code do? Does it start & bind a service or what?

Comment: Edited the answer. Hope it helps.